# php is not returning an array

Tags: php, arrays, return-value

i'm probably make a really stupid mistake, but i can't find it.

i'm trying to return an array, and it just isn't working.

the count of $temp_array is 33 which is the correct number it should be, the count of $dropdown_array is 1. what am i doing wrong?

```
<?php
function dropmaker($stuff) {

require '../connect.php';

$dropdown_query = "SELECT $stuff FROM maps_sku_groups GROUP BY $stuff;";
$dropdown_result = mysqli_query($link, $dropdown_query);
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($dropdown_result)) {
    $temp_array[] = $data[$stuff];
}
echo count($temp_array);
return array($temp_array);
}?>

<?php 
$dropdown_array[] = dropmaker('cyclecount');
echo count($dropdown_array);
?>
```

Comment: I wouldn't include a file in a function! or at least use: require_once

Comment: did you try using var_dump($arrayname) or print_r($arrayname) to see the results? Also, as @Rizier123 mentioned, don't include a connection inside a function. Require it once at the top of your script, this can cause bugs.

Comment: i can't seem to get the function to work at all without having the file in it. which also makes no sense to me...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are returning an array, which contains the array `$temp_array` as its only element. Just return `$temp_array` directly, and it should work.

**EDIT (Thanks @Rizier123)**: Additionally, you are assigning the result of the call to `dropmaker()` to `$dropdown_array[]`, which inserts the result of the function call into the (previously non-existing) array `$dropdown_array`, so `$dropdown_array` becomes an array with the function result as its only element.

Comment: Also he don't have to write this: `$dropdown_array[]` only `$dropdown_array`

Comment: e. g a simple `var_dump($dropdown_array)` would've shown this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
    function dropmaker($stuff) {

    require '../connect.php';

    $dropdown_query = "SELECT $stuff FROM maps_sku_groups GROUP BY $stuff;";
    $dropdown_result = mysqli_query($link, $dropdown_query);
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($dropdown_result)) {
        $temp_array[] = $data[$stuff];
    }
    echo count($temp_array);
    return $temp_array;
    }?>

    <?php 
    $dropdown_array = dropmaker('cyclecount');
    echo count($dropdown_array);
    ?>
```

Your function returns array of array since you have written `return array($temp_array);`

And also you are assigning this return value to first index of array $dropdown_array so the count of this variable remains 1

Comment: when doing this it still is 33 & 1

the var_dump gives this: (which is one level less than my previous iteration.)
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=33)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line `$dropdown_array[] = dropmaker('cyclecount');` you're assigning the return value of `dropmaker()`, an array, to the first element of the array `$dropdown_array[]` rather than assigning `$dropdown_array` to the array itself.

Try this code

`$dropdown_array = dropmaker('cyclecount');`

Removing the `[]` is fixing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code :

`return array($temp_array)`  instead of   `return $temp_array`

Also `$dropdown_array[]`  instead of `$dropdown_array`